# IndexPath in cells after atomic update

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, atomic, nsindexpath

I have this function that it will be triggered every time a user changes his picture, and will get the profilePictureUrl of the current user and update all posts matching the currentUser in the database. Works fine! Is doing the job. How do I update the indexPath of those particular cells? Right now my cells images are empty after the update.

```
    var pathToPictures = [Pictures]()
func updateAllImagesOfCurrentUserInDatabase() {

    //refrences
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    //match the user ID value stored into posts with current userID and get all the posts of the user
    let update = ref.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
    update.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.pathToPictures.removeAll()

        if snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] != nil {
        let results = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

        for (_, value) in results {
            let pathToPostPicture = Pictures()

            if let pathToImage = value["pathToImage"] as? String , let postID = value["postID"] as? String {
                pathToPostPicture.postImageUrl = pathToImage
                pathToPostPicture.postID = postID
                self.pathToPictures.append(pathToPostPicture)
                print("Image and POST ID: \(pathToPostPicture.postImageUrl!)")
                print("Post ID is : \(postID)")

                if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == uid {
                ref.child("Users_Details").child(uid!).child("profileImageUrl").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (userSnapshot) in
                    print(userSnapshot)

                    let userIMageUrl = userSnapshot.value as! String
                    pathToPostPicture.postImageUrl = userIMageUrl
                    self.pathToPictures.append(pathToPostPicture)
                    print("This is the image path:" + userIMageUrl + String(self.pathToPictures.count))

                    // Update the Database

                    let postIDCount = pathToPostPicture.postID!
                    let updatedUserData = ["posts/\(postIDCount)/pathToImage": pathToPostPicture.postImageUrl!]
                    print("This is THE DATA:" , updatedUserData)
                    ref.updateChildValues(updatedUserData as Any as! [AnyHashable : Any])

                })
                }
                print(self.pathToPictures.count)
            }
            }
        } else {
            print("snapshot is nill - add some data")
        }

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Use an appropriate data source model which includes the image (or the URL to the image) and reload the table view.

Comment: I do have the model that includes image URL of the image (pathToPictures) and I am reloading the collectionView when it finishes. In the database everything is correct, but in the app, I don't think it's updating the cells properly after the changes being made.

Comment: In `cellForItem` you have to create the image from the actual URL or first you have to update the image URL of the particular user in the data model.

Comment: cell.profileImageView.downloadImage(from: self.posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage) ... I am doing this with this line, downloadImage is a ImageView extension that downloads the picture by the url and display it directly in the cell. "posts" is the Array where everything gets loaded. When the fetch function gets triggered my array it's populated with the information from posts. Works well until the update. This is where my cell pictures just disappear. Any thoughts?

Comment: Personally I'd prefer a download manager which works independently from the cells (which can be deallocated and reused) but regardless of the way to download the data you have to inform the mechanism to update the UI that the data has been changed.

Comment: how do I do that? or better when... I am trigering the update function from  viewDidAppear... It is not getting triggerd twice in case no data  has to be changed, only if the imagePath do not match. Give me an example if you can!

Comment: I mean something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I am using DispatchAsync in my download manager - the image view extension, I even tried with a timer after the code gets executed to be the last ones! I tried from the collection view the same thing with the timer getting the image asynchronously.